# kubernetes nodeport expose service error

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am exposed the service `mongodb` in `nodePort` but I cannot access that link. Connection was reset error:

```
$ curl http://192.168.99.102:32292
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

$ kubectl.exe get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP           4d
mongodb      NodePort    10.0.0.213   <none>        27017:32292/TCP   7m
```

Comment: mongodb doesn't speak http. You can't connect to it with curl.

Comment: I tried without http. got connection refused error

Comment: $ curl 192.168.99.102:32292
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.102 port 32292: Connection refused

Comment: http is a protocol, not just part of a url.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/mongodb 27017:27017
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't connect to the port 27017 via HTTP.
Try this `telnet 192.168.99.102 32292`.